# Delete cells if job sheet no longer exists

Tags: vba, excel

Everyone;

I have this bit of code that copies data from worksheets with a numeric name (a job number) and pasts them into a column +1 on a master sheet to be email off every night.

I want to delete job pages when the jobs are complete. When I delete a page, my data isn't being removed from the Master Email sheet.

How can I modify this code to delete from cells 18-39 in column XXX if the value in cell 19 (the job number) is no longer in the workbook?

Thanks for any help!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim ws, MASTER111 As Worksheet
    Dim ColIndex As Integer
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER111")

    ColIndex = 2 'first column on Master sheet to paste data
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then
           Master.Cells(19, ColIndex) = ws.Range("A1") 'put job name in first row
           Set CopyRange = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range("N:N"))
           CopyRange.Copy
           Master.Cells(16, ColIndex).PasteSpecial xlValues
           Master.Cells(18, ColIndex) = "Job #"
           Master.Cells(19, ColIndex) = ws.Range("A1") 'put job name in first row
           ColIndex = ColIndex + 1
           Set CopyRange = Nothing
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using [Range.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-clear-method-excel) If a condition is met like `If Cells(19,ColIndex)="" Then Range(Cells(18,ColIndex),Cells(39,ColIndex)).Clear` If 19 is blank then....

Comment: You haven't shown any attempt of your own. Did you think we would write this all for you? As it stands, *this question is too broad*.

Comment: @CallumDA I'm hoping someone who knows more than I do would have a more eloquent solution than I could come up with. I was going to make a 'table of contents' and delete the cells if values weren't present in the table... but that is a junk way of doing this. I'm still very new to all this.

Comment: @danieltakeshi I took your advice and have the code below. This is working for one column (A). How do i extend this down to, like, AA?
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim colindex As Integer
  colindex = 1
 If Cells(2, colindex) = "0" Then Range(Cells(4, colindex), Cells(8, colindex)).Clear
  
End Sub`

Comment: @mystic_muffin you have to add the code on your loop, right after `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: @danieltakeshi by doing this is seems to interrupt my loop and paste all my data into one column A. I can see the data flashing all in one cell before it settles on the last set of data it's supposed to paste in.

Comment: @mystic_muffin Are you using the increment on the counter? `ColIndex = ColIndex + 1` If you don't, it just loops on `ColIndex = 1` that is column A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your code as sample, if you want to clear on change of events on the desired Sheet.

> Add the code to the desired Sheet. Not on Modules. e.g.: Sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo CleanExit
If Cells(2, Target.Column) = "0" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range(Cells(4, Target.Column), Cells(8, Target.Column)).Clear
End If
CleanExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And next time try to edit you question with your new code, don't post large codes on comment.

Comment: Thanks so much! I get so nervous being so green and working with deleting data. I really appreciate all of the help.